# Customizing Laravel's Authenticate method doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I followed the documentation and overrode the Authenticate method: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#authenticating-users

However, it still doesn't run. I mean my custom code is not run when the user logs in.
I copy-pasted the entire code block from the documentation and just added a Log::info into it, so if it ran, I'd see "Hello from authenticate" in the logs file, but I see nothing. I also deleted everything from it and just left the Log in it, yet I get authenticated without an issue.

What did I miss?

HTTP->Controllers->Auth->LoginController: authenticate -- Using only the code below, the user still gets authenticated without a problem. But they shouldn't.

```
    public function authenticate(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        Log::info("Authenticate is started");

        return back()->withErrors([ // this is a default response if an error occured.
            'email' => 'Just testing.',
        ])->onlyInput('email');
    }
```

Edit: I did optimize:clear and composer du too, nothing changed.

Comment: Have you refreshed application with `composer du && php artisan optimize:clear`?

Comment: yes I did run both.

Comment: are you sure your login form is calling this controller?

Comment: well it's a complete "fresh" version, following the documentation. So probably yes, I didn't override anything else but this (or atleast trying to). Idk if by default authenticate method is called or not, can we check that somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" this problem (probably permanently) by overriding the `login` method instead of the `authenticate` method. Even tho the documentation specifically talks about the `authenticate` method, seems like it's never called in the login, nor the register methods, so it's just floating around.

I'll give room to people who might know an answer why - or to correct me if I'm wrong, but until then, that's that: override the `login` instead of the `authenticate`.

Answer (score 1):

Hey it looks like you're referring Laravel 10 documentation but implementing  different version of laravel instead of 10. SO the following thing you should first check,

1. Your laravel version is 10 or something other than 10? Use the following command,

   php artisan --version
2. Check if the controller you're looking for is the same which is being used for the authentication. Now if you're using laravel 10 then you should look into the following controller,

> app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthenticatedSessionController.php

Comment: --version returns: Laravel Framework 10.10.0

Comment: theres no AuthenticatedSessionController.php. theres: 
confirmpasswordcontroller, forgotpasswordc, loginc, registerc, resetpasswordc, verificationc. (c is for "controller", just shortening here)

Comment: but when I refer to the "login" method instead of the "authenticate" method, it triggers. If I do this with the authenticateD method, same, it triggers. so idk whats up with this

Comment: @ADHDisDEV here is my structure of laravel 10.10.0 https://ibb.co/K0vryTb. Can you tell me what package you're using for the login and registration ? LIke breeze, Jetstream etc.